# Update um valor em uma coluna com condicional comparando 2 colunas de 2 tabelas diferentes

Tags: sql

Em uma tabela, preciso inserir o valor **'ID Relacionado Montagem'** em um campo, com a seguinte condição:

- Esse valor só pode ser inserido quando o valor do campo "Id_tabela1" for igual aos valores que estão em um campo ("Id_tabela2") de outra tabela.

Este é o código que eu estou usando:

```
UPDATE tabela1 SET _Montagem = 'ID Relacionado Montagem' WHERE 
bancodb.dbo.tabela1.Id_tabela1 = (SELECT Id_tabela2 FROM tabela2)
```

O SQL está me retornando o seguinte erro:

```
A subconsulta retornou mais de 1 valor. Isso não é permitido quando a subconsulta segue um =, !=, <, <= , >, >= ou quando ela é usada como uma expressão.
```

Muito provavelmente por que estou usando o operador "=", gostaria de saber como posso fazer para condicionar este insert à comparação dos 2 campos.

Comment: Podes partilhar mais informação da tua estrutura das tabelas? Sem ter a certeza da estrutura, a minha melhor sugestão é usares o `IN` em vez do `=`.

Comment: Acabei de fazer isso, resolveu meu problema. Eu sou novo no SQL e não conhecia o comando IN...  Obrigado!!! :)

Comment: Boa! Publiquei como resposta, se quiseres aceitar. Caso alguém tenha um problema parecido no futuro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sem ter a certeza da estrutura, a minha melhor sugestão é [usares o `IN` em vez do `=`](http://www.dofactory.com/sql/where-in).